# Laravel Error Route "/signin/" or method "post" not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project based on Laravel. it's an old project which used PHP 5.4. Now I'm running PHP 7.2 on the server but when I open the website it shows the error in the error log. I have pecee/simple-router 3.7.0 installed which requires php >= 5.4.0. I have also tried to update it to 4.2.0.6 with `composer update pecee/simple-router` but it didn't work it shows Deprecation warning.

```
[22-May-2020 21:23:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Pecee\SimpleRouter\Exceptions\HttpException: Route "/signin/" or method "post" not allowed. in /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/Router.php:287
Stack trace:
#0 /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/SimpleRouter.php(52): Pecee\SimpleRouter\Router->routeRequest()
#1 /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/src/Application.php(97): Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter::start()
#2 /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/index.php(11): Simcify\Application->route()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/Router.php on line 287
```

Composer error

```
Deprecation warning: Your package name simcify is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
```

How can I solve this?